# MediaElement.js audio tag doesn't get style added dynamic

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, html5-audio, mediaelement.js

Hello guys one question...

I want to use MediaElement.js to wrap my audio tags so I can have the same player on all browsers...
I use JQM 1.4...

When I add the element static it works

```
<audio id="audio_element" preload="none" controls="controls">
      <source src="ClassicMelody.mp3">
      <source src="ClassicMelody.ogg">
    </audio>
```

But when I add it dynamic like this it doesn't have the MedialElement style:

```
var content =$('<div data-role="collapsible" id="set"' + naslov + '"><h3><img class="imgg" style="vertical-align: middle;margin-right:30px" src="images/'+slika+'" width="150" height="150"  /><span class="titleg" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle">'+ stevilka +'Sectionit ' + naslov + '</span></h3><p>' + kratek + '</p><audio id="audio_element" preload="none" controls="controls"><source src="'+ posneteki +'"><source src="'+ posneteka +'"></audio><a data-ajax="false" href="#" onclick="poslinapri(\''+niz+'\')" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all"><div class="prostor1tr">More</div></a></div>')

        $('#set').append(content);
        content.collapsible();
```

What can couse this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

Dynamically added *video* and *audio* tags should be initialized after appending them.

```
$('#set').append(content).collapsibleset().find('video,audio').mediaelementplayer();
```

---

You have two solutions to achieve this.

1. **Solution one:**

   Append content as an *object* and *enhance* it using `.collapsible()`.

   ```
   var content = $( $("<div/>").collapsible() );
   $("#parent").append(content);
   ```
2. **Solution two:**

   Call enhancement on *parent* div, to enhance all contents using `.enhanceWithin()`.

   ```
   var content = $("<div/>");
   $("#parent").append(content).enhanceWitin();
   ```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Qt8yT/)**

Comment: I tried both of your solutions but it doesnt seem to take effect ...and I forgot to paste all the code ... it ends like this :

$('#set').append(content);
  content.collapsible();
    };
    
    $('#set').collapsibleset();

Comment: @LitBe then its different now. collapsible are not styled or player itself?

Comment: the collapsible are ok ....  but the player is not styled ...  this is the problem ... if I use it static is ok ... dynamic in collapsible ... no style ...

Comment: @LitBe are you calling `$('video,audio').mediaelementplayer()` on them after appending? they need to be initialized.

Comment: I have this just on the end of the page... just before </body>
<script>
// using jQuery
$('video,audio').mediaelementplayer(/* Options */);
</script>

Comment: @LitBe you need to manually initialize them as they are dynamically added. check updated answer and demo.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46679/discussion-between-litbe-and-omar)